# Can't see module

Tags: module, extensions

I asked this question in stack overflow before.But didn't get any answer. So I'm putting it here as well.It's very important to me.

I installed this extension (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/alpha-bank-e-commerce-1.html) a few days ago.After installation, it broked the theme.so I disabled it through its `xml` folder.

I am in need to use it. In the admin panel at `System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced -> Disable modules` output, I can see this module. But I think this module is supposed to show it's configuration somewhere inside the `System  >  Configuration`. It should somewhat looks like  `System > Configuration > payment Methods`. But I couldn't find anything there.

Anyone who knows.. how to do it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an external extension and it has nothing to do with Magento in effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN the payment methods. last alpha bank.
clean the cache and Re index all
[image]

Comment: thank's a lot.It's working on a test mode,so i will try it in the live site.

Comment: Sorry.As new to this forum,where i supposed to put questions about extensions or similar subjects?Apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: you can put the questions about extensions or similar subjects here, or you can also ask to stack overflow with magneto tag and tag with subject name.

Comment: you can also ask me over skype jignesh261991 or jigneshsorathiya2012@gmail.com